# UINavigation bar back button in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

i am developing a application which have a activity indicator in UINavigationbar and the problem is that when i hide the activity indicator the default navigation back button not displayed  in ios 7 but in ios 6 it works perfectly

i am getting  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem  as nil when i print it in console

after hiding activity indicator i have written below code

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem];
```

Try using:

```
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem];
```

(I'm not sure if this is going to work exactly like this. It's possible that you'll have to store the back button in a variable prior to showing the activity indicator and than set the back button to that variable afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a rank beginner, but my understanding is that the back button displayed is actually a property of the the previous view controller, not of the view controller which is displayed.

Unless you've manually set a back button for the currently visible view controller, it should be nil.

Try logging the back button item from of the previous view controller in the stack, that might help